# How to convert unique row values to column names (gave 0 value in NA places)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Hallo I tried to find the answer on  stackoverflow but I failed. Is many similar questions but my point is different.

**Here is my problem:**
- I want to take unique values from one column (IAB_category) and create data frame with column names form IAB_category

```
> df
        userID IAB_category suma
 1: 0004837def          art    3
 2: 0004837def          aut    5
 3: 0004837def          bus    5
 4: 0004837def          fin    4
 5: 0004837def          hob    1                         

 405479: ffffa375db          tra   31
 405480: ffffa942e3          bus    6
 405481: ffffa942e3          fin   12
 405482: ffffa942e3          new    2
```

Basically I want to get this data frame for all users (and put suma in case when user x has some value or 0 when user x doesn't
 have sum value ('tea' will be 0 and 'new' will be 0 as well).

```
 userID       art aut bus fin hob tra new
 0004837def     3   3   5   4   1   0   0
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to spread your data from long form to wide form.  The easiest way to do that is with the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)

# Convert the dataset to wide
newdf <- spread(df, key=IAB_category, value=suma)
# Replace missing with 0
newdf <-
  lapply(newdf, function(x) {
                  x[is.na(x)] <- 0
                  x
                })
```